# ERROR flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows

Tags: flume

```
I have one flume agent with one exec source, two custom channels and two hdfs sinks. while starting the agent, it gives me an error saying ERROR flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed.
```

My config file goes as

```
agent.sources = source
agent.sinks = sink1 sink2
agent.channels = channel1 channel2

agent.sources.source.type = exec
agent.sources.source.command = cat /home/Flume/XMLFiles/
agent.sources.source.channels = channel1 channel2
agent.sources.source.selector.type = replicating

agent.channels.channel1.type = com.flume.Channel1
agent.channels.channel1.type = file
agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 100000
agent.channels.channel1.checkpointInterval = 3000

agent.channels.channel2.type = com.flume.Channel2
agent.channels.channel2.type = file
agent.channels.channel2.transactionCapacity = 100000
agent.channels.channel2.checkpointInterval = 3000

agent.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://ip:port/user/Channel1
agent.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = test
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .log
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 1200
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

agent.sinks.sink2.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.path = hdfs://ip:port/user/Channel2
agent.sinks.sink2.channel = channel2
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.filePrefix = test
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.fileSuffix = .log
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.rollInterval = 1200
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent.sinks.sink2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

agent.sources.source.channels = channel1 channel2
agent.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
agent.sinks.sink2.channel = channel2

My error log says

14/03/18 13:32:10 ERROR file.FileChannel: Failed to start the file channel [channel=channel1]
```

java.io.IOException: Cannot lock /home/.flume/file-channel/checkpoint. The directory is already locked. [channel=channel1]
        at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.lock(Log.java:802)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.(Log.java:201)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.(Log.java:66)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log$Builder.build(Log.java:167)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:242)
        at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:236)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: I am using flume 1.2.0

Comment: The issue is now solved.

Answer (score 5):

you cant use two filechannel in same dir,because there is a write lock in filechannel dir.you need to specific different dir for every filechannel.such as:

```
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir = /mnt/flume/checkpoint
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /mnt/flume/data
a1.channels.c2.checkpointDir = /mnt/flume2/checkpoint
a1.channels.c2.dataDirs = /mnt/flume2/data
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thx @edwardsbean